# Transaction failed, funds never returned to sender

Tags: metamask, failed-transaction

I made a transaction two days ago through metamask to a wallet in an exchanger.
The transaction failed due to out of gas but I neither received my funds back to my wallet nor to my wallet in the exchanger.
The transaction appears as confirmed on metamask. But when i see it on ehterscan it says it failed due to out of gas.
What could have happened? the amount was around $85 and the fees around $3. I understand that the fees are lost but what about the rest of the ETH?

Comment: can you share the transaction hash?

Comment: For failed transaction only the transaction fees are paid, other funds were never transferred. There are two posibilites: 1/ the wallet has a bug then contact customer support or use a better wallet/exchanger, 2/ the balances are correct, check the transaction history on a block explorer.